# Fix point operation

Tags: functions, category-theory

Given a function $f: A \to B$ is there a function $T: B \times B$ such that for any
$g: A \to B$ we have $T \circ g = (f, g)$?

Note that for $f = (A \xrightarrow{!} 1 \xrightarrow{x} B)$ it is true: take
$T = (x \circ !, id)$, then $T \circ g = (x \circ ! \circ g, id \circ g) = (x \circ !, g)$.

(Here, $1 = \{ * \}$ is set of one element, and for any set $M$ there
is a unique function $!: M \to 1$ defined by $m \mapsto *$).

If for a generic $f$ it is false, please give an example.

Answer (score 1):

There often is no such function $T$. For an easy example, consider $A=B=\{1,2\}$, $f=id$ and $g\equiv 1$.

Then the image of $T \circ g$ for any $T$ has cardinality 1, as the image of $g$ has cardinality $1$, but the image of $(f,g)$ has cardinality 2.